# Want to download my database backup through bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to dump my database in a spacific date in a spacific directory,database dump normally with script but it will not dump in mentioned directory - dump under only "/" directory not spacified directory.  Here my script-

```
#! /bin/bash
now=$(date +%d)
if [ "$now" == 1 ] | [ "$now" == 4 ] | [ "$now" == 7 ]
then
BACKUP_DIR="/backup/database/week1"
elif [ "$now" == 10 ] | [ "$now" == 13 ]
then
BACKUP_DIR="/backup/database/week2"
elif [ "$now" == 16 ] | [ "$now" == 19 ]
then
BACKUP_DIR="/backup/database/week3"
elif [ "$now" == 22 ] | [ "$now" == 25 ] | [ "$now" == 28 ] | [ "$now" == 31 ]
then
BACKUP_DIR="/backup/database/week4"
fi

TIMESTAMP=$(date -u +"%d-%m-%Y")
MYSQL_USER="backupuser"
MYSQL=/usr/bin/mysql
MYSQL_PASSWORD="efeww2"
MYSQLDUMP=/usr/bin/mysqldump
mkdir -p "$BACKUP_DIR/$TIMESTAMP"

databases=`$MYSQL --user=$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | grep -Ev "(Database|mysql|information_schema|performance_schema|phpmyadmin)"`

for db in $databases; do
  $MYSQLDUMP --force --opt --user=$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD --databases $db > $BACKUP_DIR/$TIMESTAMP/$db-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).sql
done
```

Comment: we should use `||` instead of `|` in `if` and `elif` condition

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue with `OR` operator which you are using.

SYNTAX:

```
if [ condition1 ] || [ condition2 ]
```

Try the below code:

```
#! /bin/bash
now=$(date +%d)
if [ "$now" == 1 ] || [ "$now" == 4 ] || [ "$now" == 7 ]
then
BACKUP_DIR="/backup/database/week1"
elif [ "$now" == 10 ] || [ "$now" == 13 ]
then
BACKUP_DIR="/backup/database/week2"
elif [ "$now" == 16 ] || [ "$now" == 19 ]
then
BACKUP_DIR="/backup/database/week3"
elif [ "$now" == 22 ] || [ "$now" == 25 ] || [ "$now" == 28 ] || [ "$now" == 31 ]
then
BACKUP_DIR="/backup/database/week4"
fi

....
....
```

I'm not sure why you are skipping a few days like 2,3,5,...

I suggest you  to use with the below option if you are triying with month of the week with respect to calander.

```
 now=`echo $((($(date +%-d)-1)/7+1))`
 if [ "$now" -eq 1 ]; then
    BACKUP_DIR="/backup/database/week1"
 elif [ "$now" -eq 2 ]; then
    BACKUP_DIR="/backup/database/week2"
 elif [ "$now" -eq 3 ]; then
    BACKUP_DIR="/backup/database/week3"
 else
    BACKUP_DIR="/backup/database/week4"
 fi
 ...
 ...
```

or if you woud like to have literal 7 days week, try below:

```
now=$(date +%d)
 if [ "$now" -le 7 ]; then
    BACKUP_DIR="/backup/database/week1"
 elif [ "$now" -le 14 ]; then
    BACKUP_DIR="/backup/database/week2"
 elif [ "$now" -le 21 ]; then
    BACKUP_DIR="/backup/database/week3"
 else
    BACKUP_DIR="/backup/database/week4"
 fi
```

Comment: I want to dump the database in spacific date in spacific directory. With my syntax database dump in mentioned date but it will dump in "/" directory instead of "/backup/database/week1..4" directory.

Comment: Yes I have tried, now the database is dump in mentioned path. Thank u.

Comment: @AniketBiswas you can accept the answer if it works.